# highcharts-ng: Equivalent of $('#container').highcharts()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I have created the chart's config in my controller like this:

```
$scope.ohlcChartConfig = {            
        options: {.......
```

like the way it is done in HighCharts-ng(angularJS directive of HighCharts).

I want the equivalent of the following :

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
```

So that I am able to call the following methods in highcharts-ng:

```
var svg = chart.getSVG();
chart.xAxis[0].addPlotBand({...})
chart.xAxis[0].removePlotBand('plot-id');
```

Currently, I have tried to do it like this:

```
var chart= $scope.ohlcChartConfig;
```

But when I call the methods, I get the error '**undefined is not a function**'.

Here is a very simplified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxGq4/) where I am trying to get the charts object and call methods on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle or plnkr?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fxGq4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just looked into sources on `highcharts-ng` - variable `chart` isn't returned anywhere, so you don't have access to methods directly from Highcharts API.

However, you can simply workaround this:

```
var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
```

`Highcharts.charts` array contains all charts on a page. See simple demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/fxGq4/2/

Note: When using `getSVG()` method, created is new chart in a background, so `Highcharts.charts` array will get more charts, or `undefined` when chart is destroyed.

Also, don't forget to add exporting.js file! Url: `http://code.highcharts.com/exporting.js`.

Comment: Please take a look at this new question as well
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551547/highcharts-ng-display-chart-on-canvas-with-tooltip

Comment: Well, good luck with that. I advice to read about adding events to canvas. You just can't take SVG, convert to canvas and expect to get tooltip as well..